# Prove that $\bar A=\bar B \iff d(x,A)=d(x,B)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that $\bar A = \bar B \iff d(x,A)=d(x,B)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

There is a lemma which states that $\exists x_0\in \bar A$ such that $d(x,A)=d(x,x_0)$. So for the forward direction (to prove $d(x,A)=d(x,B)$) we need to show that $x_0$ is the same for both $\bar A$ and $\bar B$. Is this obvious? Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$d(x,A)=d(x,\bar{A})$$

and I hope you know how to prove this using metric topology.